# flutter one signal not displaying notifications

Tags: flutter, push-notification, onesignal

I am trying to use One Signal and flutter to be able to add user notifications to the app, however I have run into a problem. The app receives the notification (according to the console) but does not show the notification in the phone (notification is authorized in phone config).

here is the App.dart code

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
OneSignal.shared.setAppId(
  "APP ID",
);
OneSignal.shared.setRequiresUserPrivacyConsent(true);

OneSignal.shared.promptUserForPushNotificationPermission().then((accepted) {
  print("Accepted permission: $accepted");
});
OneSignal.shared
    .setNotificationOpenedHandler((OSNotificationOpenedResult result) {
  print('NOTIFICATION OPENED HANDLER CALLED WITH: ${result}');
});

OneSignal.shared.setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler(
    (OSNotificationReceivedEvent event) {
  // Will be called whenever a notification is received in foreground
  // Display Notification, pass null param for not displaying the notification
  event.complete(event.notification);
});
return MaterialApp(
  builder: (context, widget) => ResponsiveWrapper.builder(
      BouncingScrollWrapper.builder(context, widget!),
      maxWidth: 1200,
      minWidth: 450,
      defaultScale: true,
      breakpoints: [
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.resize(450, name: MOBILE),
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(800, name: TABLET),
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(1000, name: TABLET),
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.resize(1200, name: DESKTOP),
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(2460, name: "4K"),
      ],
      background: Container(color: Color(0xFFF5F5F5))),
  home: SplashScreenView(),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}
```

And here is the console log after sending the notification from the website

> I/WM-WorkerWrapper(28728): Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=id,
> tags={ com.onesignal.OSNotificationWorkManager$NotificationWorker } ]

Answer (score 0):

**Lates Updated method**

```
    OneSignal.shared.setNotificationWillShowInForegroundHandler((OSNotificationReceivedEvent event) {
               print('FOREGROUND HANDLER CALLED WITH: ${event}');
               /// Display Notification, send null to not display
               event.complete(null);
              
                this.setState(() {
           _debugLabelString =
              "Notification received in foreground notification: \n${event.notification.jsonRepresentation().replaceAll("\\n", "\n")}";
      });
 });
```

just move the app in the background or close it and test the push notification. it will show you if everything is correctly set up. But if you want to receive a notification when the app is running & open (foreground mode) you need to manage it manually via the [flutter local notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) package.

check this one signal official [link](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v7.0/docs/flutter-sdk-200) this method is mentioned.

> This function/callback will be called whenever your application
> receives a notification from OneSignal when the app is in the
> foreground.

```
OneSignal.shared.setNotificationReceivedHandler((OSNotification notification) {
  // a notification has been received
});
```

above method, you can fire local notification when you received push notification while the app is in the foreground mode.

Comment: documentation is outdated. that doesnt work anymore on the current flutter pub get, also App doesnt get the notification neither foreground or background

Comment: can you try an updated answer?